# Can file extensions be associated with TS2008 Remote Applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, remoteapp

Just wondering if there's any way to associate a local file extension with a remote app running via a Windows 2008 Terminal Services session?

If, for example, I've published Acrobat as a Remote App, is there any way of making it launch when I double-click a .PDF file? I'm guessing that this isn't possible, given that the server would need access to the file in question, but just wanted to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the .MSI creator in Remote App Manager on the server. There is an option to create a file association for the Remote App,